# Bash: mate : command not found

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

Hi I am learning how to use Github online via Udemy course. The instructor is accessing textmate editor using MAC OS. However I am **trying to access textmate editor** in **Windows 10**. When in Git bash I type

```
 mate file_name.txt
```

It throws an **error**

```
bash: mate: command not found.
```

How can this be resolved. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are on Windows just use something else such as notepad or notepad++.

Comment: If the editor is installed add it to `$PATH`.

Comment: Under git bash, you can use `vi`. I don't think git bash has a package manager, so installing `mate` there is a bit of a pain (see [Installing Programs on Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1203503/installing-programs-in-git-bash)). On Windows 10, I'd recommend installing the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) for a better Linux environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Text Mate works only in MAC OS and not in Windows.** **Sublime Text** is a good **editor** to work with in **Windows**:

Steps to **open Sublime Text from Git bash** (after installing Sublime text first in system) are as follows:

In Git bash(you can open from Search) type the below 2 commands:

```
 alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"

 subl .
```

Instead of subl . you can also **open a specific file or create a new file** using below:

```
 subl Filename.txt
```

This command subl Filename.txt will create a new file with name as Filename.txt otherwise will open an existing file with the same name if the file already exists.

Comment: Hi 

I am using alias command in Git bash. Thanks for pointing this out, editing my comment. :)